# Как округлить края кнопки (button). android??

Tags: android, java

Как округлить края кнопки (button). android??

Answer (score 5):

В качестве примера:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ceb623" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```